# Scrollview has only one child but exception

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a layout with scrollview and some linear layout. And look at my code there is only one linear layout which is the **only one child** of the scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mng.activity.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/home_menu">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/st">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="57dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_reading"
                        android:id="@+id/image" />

                    <TextView
                            android:text="@string/student"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/student"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/pa">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="57dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/imageVie2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/parent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.39"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/te">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="57dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_teacher"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/teacher"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/teacher"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/ac">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="57dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account"
                        android:id="@+id/imageVie" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/my_account"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/account"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tools">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tools"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/students"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

it shows exception

```
                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
                                                                                              at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:237)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1308)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried clean project that didn't helped me

Comment: is that the same activity?..your XML does not contain any error

Comment: I tried running your code and it's working perfectly on my device

Comment: share your activity code

Comment: post your .java, I think you might have mistakenly tried to add views in ScrollView instead of LinearLayout

Comment: Yes Nailabja is correct

Comment: as exception said, `ScrollView can host only one direct child`. What is not clear for you in **only one direct child**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I found it.It is because I dynamically replaced the content with a fragment.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_home,new StudentFragment(),"student");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be adding some view to scrollview in your java file. So don't add any view to scrollview.

```
scrollview.addView(someView); // Remove any code like this
```